# I am using single page application via ajax in mvc?

Tags: javascript

I am using single page application via ajax in MVC
but when I use window .history.pushstate and window. popstate I am getting an error like

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>   send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8720
>   ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8150
>   load @ (index):468
>   window.onpopstate @ (index):426"

How to fix this issue?  here my ajax call

```
<script>
    $('#loadingImage').hide();
    $('.jq-navigation-link').click(function () {
        debugger

        var url = $(this).data('url');

        loadPartial(url)

    })
    function loadPartial(url)
    {
        debugger
        $('#renderPartial').html("");
        $('#loadingImage').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "?ispartial=" + true,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                $('#loadingImage').hide();
                $('#renderPartial').html(data);
            }
        })

        window.history.pushState({ url: url }, '', url);

        window.onpopstate = function (event) {
            debugger
            if (event.state)
            {
                var previousUrl = "location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state);
                loadPartial(previousUrl);
            }


        };
    }


</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to use `http-server`

Comment: this may solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936500/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-http-data-chrom

Comment: Are you using file://?

Comment: @plumSemPy, No i guess